# Custom Roles for MVC Intranet Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC Intranet application and I use Generic Principal Object based on custom roles for authentication.

My question is how can I persist the Generic principal object across requests. I am using the below code. But I need to execute the below code for each user requests since there is no mechanism to persists the user roles across requests. Please note that I don't like to use session in my MVC project.

```
 private  GenericPrincipal GetGenericPrincipal()
        {
            // Use values from the current WindowsIdentity to construct 
            // a set of GenericPrincipal roles.
            WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            // Construct a GenericIdentity object based on the current Windows 
            // identity name and authentication type. 
            string authenticationType = windowsIdentity.AuthenticationType;
            string userName = windowsIdentity.Name;
            GenericIdentity genericIdentity =
                new GenericIdentity(userName, authenticationType);

            // Construct a GenericPrincipal object based on the generic identity 
            // and custom roles for the user.
            GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal =
                new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, GetUserRoles(userName));

            return genericPrincipal;
        }


    }



 HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = GetGenericPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my existing projects I get the principal per-request using the `Application_AuthenticateRequestion()` method in `Global.asax.cs`.  The main choke-point is retrieving the `User` from the database, but this problem is overcome by data-caching the `User` object in memory behind the scenes.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(formsIdentity);

        EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress(ticket.Name);

        var user = this.UserService.GetUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

        if (user != null)
        {
            foreach (var role in user.Roles)
            {
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }
        }

        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Note: I have a reference to my global cache that is passed into my service class.  This what the cache is using.  It uses the basic cache technique of trying to get the cached item from the cache, if it isn't there (i.e. it's null) then fetch it from the database and store it in the cache for next time.

*From UserService.cs*

```
public User GetUserByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress)
{
    if (emailAddress == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("emailAddress");
    }

    User user = this.dataCache.Get(emailAddress.Address) as User;

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = this.userRepository.GetUserByUsername(emailAddress);

        if (user != null)
        {
            this.dataCache.Set(emailAddress.Address, user);
        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thompson, Many thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how you Cache the user data ? I am very new to MVC.

Comment: For my version that's in development I use .NET's `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`.  You'll need to declare this globally, maybe in `global.asax.cs` also (I personally use an IoC container called Ninject to provide me this in singleton scope, but this might be a bit beyond what you need).  I then use the methods on this class to get and set the user object in the cache.  I've updated my answer with more code.